# How can I write plot title and axis titles with matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I developed a python script that plots data from netcdf files. The problem is that I try to modify the title of the plot ( and in other cases I also tried to change x axis title with ax.set_xlabel('etc') ) but python seems not answering.
The data are extracted using xarray and then are plotted using matplotlib.
This is my code:

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")  # Get users home directory
file = home + '/Desktop/Tesi/Triennial_EOFs/'  # Adjust if necessary
path = file + 'normevectortime1905_1.nc'

mask  = xr.open_dataset(path, decode_times=False)                 #extract variables in xarray from .nc file
in_variable='msl'
var = mask[in_variable]                      #variable to study

ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1, projection=proj)
ax.set_title('PLOT')
ax.set_xlabel('x axes_test')
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m',linewidth=0.4)
var[0,:,:].plot.contourf(transform=crs.PlateCarree(),levels=20)

plt.show()
```

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RYUK.png)

Moreover I never explicitly written code lines for the colorbar or the text related to the variable field near the colorbar. And I never even wrote instructions for written time on the top of the plot.

Comment: Seems that xarray's plot function sets the title and labels itself. Possibly you can just set them *after* the plotting to override what xarray put there.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, but how can I do this? What do I have to write after the code above?

Comment: What I mean is, try to put the line `ax.set_title('PLOT')` ***after*** the contour.

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem solved